# Bootstrap layout: 2 columns split 66/33% or 1 column 100% when the 2nd column hidden

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, mixins

I have a Bootstrap 3 layout like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

Normally this displays the first column as 66% and the second column as 33%

When I have no content for the second column, I want to be able to hide it and make the first column take up 100% width. I think it can be done with a mixins but while I'm trying to get that working, is there a better way?

Comment: I am interested in this question as well. I feel like there should be a clean Css solution to this w/o using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

If it's empty you can add the class `.col-md-12` after col-md-8 and add class `.hide` to the col-md-4. I don't know how you're implementing your site. If it's a CMS, you can have a little checkbox to add these classes if col-md-4 == empty.

If you're hiding at different breakpoints, look at the responsive utilities section of the TWB docs.